# Using jQuery to get the next or previous element from a selection

Tags: jquery

How can I get the previous or next element from a jQuery selection?

Basically, I will have a set of elements, say all inputs:

```
$('input')
```

When I have a single input, I also need to get the previous and next input.
Something like:

```
$(this).prev('input')
$(this).next('input')
```

However, the inputs are not siblings and I don't want just the next DOM element. I want the next element in the jQuery selection (inputs in this case).

I know I can iterate through a jQuery selection with

```
.each(function(...
```

But I don't need to go over all of the elements, just the one before and after.

The elements will also be dynamically ordered (using jQuery UI sortables).

Comment: so are the next, children and the previous a parent?

Comment: They are in different div containers for the sortable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var inp = $('input');

var index = inp.index(this);
var next = inp[index+1];
var prev = inp[index-1];
```

Note that `prev` and `next`, just like this are not jQuery objects but DOM object now. To make them jQuery objects you need to wrap them in the `$()` function.

Answer (score 8):

jQuery has built in support as required by you,

```
$($('input')[0]).next('input')
```

[next](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next#expr)

```
 $($('input')[0]).prev('input')
```

[previous](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev#expr)